# ASP.NET MVC 4 Adding a list of class items to a class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building a database of concerts that I have been to and the songs that were played. I have 2 class, a Show class and a Song class. The Show class has a List. I would like to know how to add songs to the show on the front end of the application. Right now I am using the default CRUD provided by Microsoft. It is in a basic format right now. I have added the class definitions below as well as the Create.cshtml for the Show class:

```
public class Show
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Venue { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String City { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String State { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime ShowDate { get; set; }

    public List<Song> TrackList { get; set; }
}

public class Song
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ShowID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Title { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan Length { get; set; }
    public String Notes { get; set; }
}
```

Create.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Show</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Venue)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Venue)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Venue)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.City)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.State)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.State)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.State)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.Label("Date")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ShowDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ShowDate)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I think you may have to add the ShowID to the song class, add a virtual Show property to the song class. Then, every time you add a song, you can update your the show table.  You will have access to it because of the property.

Comment: So, I have the ShowID in the Song class. I would also need to add a virtual Show property as well?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. In order to navigate to the Show, you will need that property.

Comment: That's not quite all you need to do, that will create a navigation property in the Entity Framework, which you may not even be using. You need to A) create the controls in your view where you select all the tracks (a list of checkboxes, maybe?) B) setup your controller's Create action so that it will read in your track list C) pass the songs and the show data to your data layer where it can be saved into a junction table